# How to move search box from header to centre of webpage in Opencart?

Tags: php, opencart

I want to move search box from header to center of web page. For this I am doing this:

removed code `<?php echo $search; ?>` from `header.tpl` and placed in `home.tpl` in container section but it's shows below error.

> Notice: Undefined variable: search in
>   /var/www/html/oc/catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/home.tpl
>   on line 2

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to move code between controllers too

Comment: can you please explain me in detail, which code i need to move? I am new to opencart.

Comment: check answer I have added code to insert in controller of header (considering you are using OpenCart version 2.2)

Comment: @Monika
 
Search box is moved and that error is also not showing but search box is not showing search results on search page

Comment: @Monika Thanks :) It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get search code work in home.tpl, you need to add below code in home.php (its controller : catalog/controller/common/home.php)

```
$data['search'] = $this->load->controller('common/search');
```

Edit -

Also you need to change js code in file catalog/view/javascript/common.js
Line no - 53

```
/* Search */
$('#search input[name=\'search\']').parent().find('button').on('click', function() {
    var url = $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=product/search';
    var value = $('input[name=\'search\']').val();
    if (value) {
        url += '&search=' + encodeURIComponent(value);
    }
    location = url;
});

$('#search input[name=\'search\']').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $('input[name=\'search\']').parent().find('button').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Hope this help you.
Tested on OpenCart version 2.2.

Comment: Search box is moved and that error is also not showing but search box is not showing search results on search page.

Comment: Please check edited answer. You need to change js code also.